# How to get a result in Integration

Tags: calculus

> $$I(a)=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} \frac{tan^{-1}ax}{x\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} dx$$

Using Leibniz's formula,

$$I'(a)=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \frac{tan^{-1}ax}{x\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} dx$$ $$=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x}{1+a^{2}x^{2}}×\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} dx$$

$x=\frac{1}{t}$

$$I'(a)=\displaystyle\int_{1}^{∞} \frac{t}{(a^{2}+t^{2})\sqrt{t^{2}-1}} dt$$

$t^{2}-1=p^{2}$

$$I'(a)=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{∞} \frac{p}{(a^{2}+p^{2}+1)|p|} dp$$

What to do next?

Comment: Of course, for $|p| \geq 0$ we have $|p| = p$.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Note since $p>0$
$$ I'(a)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{p}{(a^2+1+p^2)|p|}dp=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{a^2+1+p^2}dp. $$
Then using $\int\frac{1}{a^2+x^2}dx=\frac{1}{a}\arctan\frac{x}{a}+c$, you will get the answer.